# How to Statefully Fuzz in Foundry without Invariants?

Tags: testing, foundry, forge, fuzz-test, invariant-test

I want to Statefully (not Statelessly) Fuzz my Protocol.

However, **I don't have any Invariants to check.**
I just want to call all of my Protocol's functions, and see if anything breaks.

**This is my `Invariant.t.sol` testing Contract:**

```js
contract Invariant is StdInvariant, Test {

    Handler handler;

    function setUp() external {

        // Deploy handler
        handler = new Handler();

        // Build handlerSelectors
        bytes4[] memory handlerSelectors = new bytes4[](3);
        handlerSelectors[0] = Handler.function1.selector;
        handlerSelectors[1] = Handler.function2.selector;
        handlerSelectors[2] = Handler.skipTime.selector;

        // Target selectors
        targetSelector(
            FuzzSelector({
                addr: address(handler),
                selectors: handlerSelectors
            })
        );

        // Target handler contract
        targetContract(address(handler));
    }

    function invariant_callHandlerFunctions() external {
        // Note: leaving this empty doesn't work
        // assert(true); // Note: doesn't work
        // Question: what should I do here?
    }
}
```

**As a workaround, I made `Fuzz.t.sol`:**

```js
contract Fuzz is Test {

    enum HandlerFunctions { Function1, Function2, SkipTime }

    Handler handler;

    function test(uint[] calldata randomness) external {
        
        // Loop randomness
        for (uint i = 0; i < randomness.length; i++) {

            // Get functionToCall
            uint functionToCall = randomness[i] % (uint(type(HandlerFunctions).max) + 1);

            if (action == uint(Action.Function1)) {
                handler.function1();

            } else if (action == uint(Action.Function2)) {
                handler.function2();

            } else if (action == uint(Action.SkipTime)) {
                handler.skipTime();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This calls all `Handler` functions (like I want to).

However, if I find a bug (and run the test again), the next run shows a different bug.

I know I can set a `seed` in `foundry.toml` (**but `seed` doesn't seem to work with this method).**

How can I fuzz Statefully (without checking Invariants)?